# Embarcadero C++ builder Excel Automation C++ does not quit

Tags: c++, excel, automation, c++builder

I am trying to Automate Excel so that it generates a report on a server and then emails this to a user when requested. The problem I have is that once I have created an excel document and written the data into it, the program does not not quit even after issuing the pXL->Quit(); command.
This is what my instructions for "closing" excel:

```
pXL->Workbooks->Close(LCID(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT));
pXLWSs.Reset(); //Releases Worksheets
pXLWS.Reset();//Releases Workbooks
pXL->Quit();// "Quits" Excel  ---> This does not quit excel
pXL.Reset();//Release Excel application?
CoUninitialize();//Uninitialise COMS
```

I have read quite a few articles and blog about this particular issue and it seems that this is because I am not freeing all the COMS associated with Excel. So I tried uninitialising COMS a few times. I issued the

```
CoUninitialize();
```

4 times and this worked! But to my disappointment, it does not work all the time.

Does anyone know how to gracefully close Excel?

I know Microsoft does not support server side Excel Automation but I was hoping to find a work around. 
I am also aware that you can simply

```
WinExec("taskkill /F /IM \"excel.exe\"",0);
```

which kills Excel altogether but I am worried about the future of the app when it will be generating quite a number of excel applications in which case I would have to kill Excel individually and it all just gets messy from there....

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What data types are pXL, pXLWSs, and PXLWS?

Comment: Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/q/4852135/25507 and see if that applies to your situation.

Comment: They are COM interfaces. TComInterface<Excel_xp::_Application>pXL;

Comment: And I've been to that page before too

Comment: @JoshKelley - So have you heard or seen anything new coz I haven't and I still have this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

So I finally came up with a way to kill what is left of Excel running in the background.

When I create Excel, I store its PID(Process Identifier) using:

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId((HWND)pXL->Hwnd, &ExcelprocessID);
```

Then after writing data when its time to kill the application:

```
pXL->Workbooks->Close(LCID(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT));
pXLWSs.Reset();
// Better to use "Reset", which will clear all references to this pointer
// rather than "Release", which will only clear the last reference
pXLWS.Reset();
pXL->Quit();
pXL.Reset();
CoUninitialize();

if ( ExcelprocessID == 0 )
{
    ShowMessage("Could not find Excel ProcessID to close");
}

else
{
    HANDLE tmpHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, ExcelprocessID);
    if (NULL != tmpHandle)
    {
        TerminateProcess(tmpHandle, 0);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else who's been looking for a solution....

Comment: btw, pXL is the application pointer that for the wrapper that I used for Excel...